# Tethering DSLR camera to PC via any common WiFi network

Tags: sony-alpha, wifi, tethering

I am aware that it is possible to tether a camera to PC via the WiFi network that is created by the WiFi-enabled camera itself. But I want to know if it is possible to tether by connecting both camera and PC to any other common WiFi network.

Specifically, I am using Sony Alpha6400 and [qDSLRDashboard](https://dslrdashboard.info/) as PC client for tethering. I connected the camera to my home WiFi network (to which my PC is connected). But I do not know how to go ahead. qDSLRDashboard does not seem to recognize the camera connected to same WiFi network.

Note: I have not tried this in Sony Imaging Edge. This question is specific to qDSLRDashboard.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: How does qDSLRDashboard identify the camera? By its IP address? Using some name on the network? How can you tell that the camera is indeed connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: toolbar of qDSLRDashboard]

According to the [documentation](https://dslrdashboard.info/connection-screen-buttons/), the network button (which looks like a single square connected to three squares, #2 in the above photo) is for connecting to a running instance of qDSLRDashboard on another PC. For example, if you have the camera connected to a laptop, you can connect to the laptop over the WiFi network with this feature. The Wireless button (#3) is for connecting to Nikon WU-1a/1b/D5300. This is not compatible with Sony cameras.

There does not appear to be any functionality for connecting to the A6400 wirelessly.